# Which MVC layer should handle a child claiming a toy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations

I have two models in my app: a `child` that `has_many :toys` and a `toy` that `belongs_to :child`. I made the db migration I needed for this to work (added `child_id` to `toys` table).

At first, children exist on their own, and toys exist on their own (with no association). At the start of every day in kindergarten, no child owns any toys. To play with a toy, a child must claim it first, and become its owner.  So, now I need to somehow implement a `child.claim(toy)` method, and here I get stuck. Specifically:

1. Should this go into the `child` controller or model? Or maybe it should be somehow split between both?
2. If it should go into the controller, should it correspond to one of the  CRUD actions or be its own thing as `def claim(toy)`?

**Edit 1:** The child is the user and is logged on via the browser. (Today's kids can do amazing things)

Comment: Who is the user of the system child or the kinder garden teacher?

Comment: The child is the user. I'll make that clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need a claim method if child is the user. You can have a `claim_toy` method in your controller. In you toys index view for each toy you can give a link as follows.

```
<%= link_to "claim", claim_toy_path(:toy_id => toy.id) %>
```

Your controller method will look something like this.

```
def claim_toy
  toy = Toy.find(params[:toy_id])
  current_child.toys << toy
end
```

simple enough. This is not a restful solution by the way.

Comment: I was under the impression it's a bad idea to have the controller do anything with the db (like `find` etc.). Is this not so?

Comment: `find` is ok for the controller, retrieving data is ok in general. But complex logic would rather be extracted.

Comment: You see if you have too much logic in your controller then its bad. That's why active record gives you methods like find, create, update and some other methods. Creating a two line method in model and calling it in controller will just make it redundant.

Comment: Thank you, that's very convincing. Accepted your answer. As a last note, could you point me towards some help for testing the controller? I mean, how do I set up those vars in the rspec test? Manually set the params hash?

Comment: sorry buddy, even I don't have any idea about testing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd build a separate class handling all the logic regarding a child and a toy. Call it context, call it concern, but do it.

```
class ToyChild # or ToyInteraction or ChildContext::Toys...

  attr_reader :toy, :child

  def initialize(toy, chid)
    @toy   = toy
    @child = child
  end

  def associate
    toy.child = child
    # could be more difficult: you should check if the child has not enough toys, if the toy is not already assigned to another child etc...
    #I'd avoid saving here since you may want to perform other operations
  end

  def foo
    #code here
  end

end
```

And in controller:

```
assoc = ToyChild.new(toy, child).associate
assoc.save
```

This style of coding:

- is easier to test
- splits responsibilities clearly
- keeps things dry (no specific code in controllers)

Comment: This is an interesting approach but I'm not sure how to go about it: Where would I place this file? How would I require it? I assume it would later also contain the "relinquish" method for when the child grows tired of the toy, right?

Comment: I follow the conventions explained in http://clean-ruby.com/ I have all my contexts in `/app/contexts` since they are under `/app` they are autoloaded. And Yes I'd put all the interaction logic within this class

Comment: Understood, thank you. I think this may be a good approach but I'm still at a loss as to how to actually implement it, so will have to go with claiming the toy via the child controller for now.

Comment: read the suggested book, you'all gain much time with maintenance

Comment: Honestly, $42 is a bit pricey for me at this point -- I'm just getting started with this whole Rails thing.

Comment: Sure, you'll learn progressively, not the most important part yet

Answer (score 2):

#### A Child is a Foreign Key on Toy

There are certainly other ways to do this, but based on your original question, the simplest solution is to make your behavior consistent with the fact that a child is associated with a toy in the Toy table.

#### Simplest Solution

Setting aside arguments about what one should do in a perfect OOP/MVC design, the sensible place to make the change is in a controller since when a child claims a toy, the claim is processed by a an #update (or perhaps even a #claim) action on the Toy controller.

> The child is the user and is logged on via the browser.

In your case, the session already knows who the child is, so adding the foreign key to the Toy model is trivial. The controller is the entity that receives the params for the associated model, so it's the correct place to tell the Toy model what attributes to update for a given toy.

There are certainly more complicated solutions, but they are of dubious merit based on the information provided in your original post. As always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. After reading your answer and watching RailsCast  398 I don't feel as bad about implementing this directly on the controller.