# Controller A calling Model B: Code smell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a `toys` controller which users can use to claim toys to play with. Right now, the `claim` method is implemented in the controller level (as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042080/592229) suggested I do).

However, now it's getting a bit fat with claiming logic that really shouldn't be there: A child can't claim a toy if they already have 3 toys, a child can't claim a toy claimed by another child, and so on. The sensible spot for that logic (in my mind) is in the `child` model, because I'm describing the behavior of a child (what they may and may not do).

That said, if I do this, the `toys#claim` controller action is going  to call methods from the `child` model. Is this a code smell/bad practice?

(I'm guessing someone's going to suggest I use a service object for this. If you do, could you please point out a simple tutorial? The recent RailsCast about this is a bit too complicated for me.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say, that both using [active record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) for anything but pure CRUD and having application logic in controller, is not only code smell but an architectural mistake. But it is in no way related to what model layer structures are used by any given controller.

Comment: I'd suggest that what you _really_ need is a `Claim` model.

Comment: @tereško: So what should I do?

Comment: @DanCheail A claim model? But this is just a simple one-to-many association that takes just a single foreign key in the `toys` table to implement. Why make another model just for that?

Comment: But it's not just a simple association—you've got a reasonably complex set of rules / validations around it. Plus, what if you want to start tracking previous claims, length of time that toys were claimed, etc?

Comment: Hmm, that's actually true, I do want to do those things. How would you see such a model working? Would it be a `has_many through`? Not sure how to go about designing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general (outside of Rails), it is not a smell at all. In fact, I'd argue that having a pure 1:1 mapping between "models" and "controllers" is a smell.

*Note:* I am not a ROR dev. I have no experience in ROR or how it implements things. However, I do understand design patterns quite well, and understand application architecture. With that said:

Instead of worrying about 1:1 mappings, step back and think about the structure of the application.

What is the Controller supposed to be doing? Well, in general it is supposed to route user actions to the application. It is just a plumbing step.

Then what is a Model (layer) supposed to be doing? In general, the Model is a layer that encompasses all of your business logic in the application. It will handle database interaction, access controls, business operations, etc. Therefore, the model is actually the vast majority of your application.

The View on the other hand is your presentational layer. It should handle all rendering, pulling data from the model layer.

Based on that understanding, your models, views and controllers should be able to vary independently to each other. In general, I'd expect to see a fairly 1:1 relationship between controllers and views. What I mean by that is that each controller that exists, I'd expect to see a view. But there can be views that exist where there's no user interaction. In those cases, you may need a controller (to render the view), or depending on your architecture, you many not need one.

But the "model classes", which are a small part of the model layer (acting as proxies or adapters for the lower model functionality) may or may not be 1:1 with controllers or views. For example, you may have a view that pulls data from multiple models. You can have a controller which acts on multiple models.

Now you could step back and say that if a controller needs to act upon multiple models, then create a new model which abstracts that operation. Sometimes that is the right thing to do. Sometimes it's not. It all boils down to the specific operations and relationships involved...

At the end of the day, there's no "right" or "wrong" here. It really comes to a design decision that you need to make as you structure your application. I wouldn't worry too much about the "smell" component, as long as it makes sense in your application...

Comment: Absolutely epic! Thank you so much.